# What are the common possible causes of POST 404 (Not Found) in Vue.js other than defining the address by typo

Tags: vue.js, http-post, axios, http-status-code-404

I know that the error message `404 (Not Found)` is thrown when you are referring to an address that doesn't exist, and one of the common causes is that you simply defined the address by mistyping, as far as I learned via some tutorial videos.

But what can be other causes, if there are any?

**[BACKGROUND]**

I'm currently trying to build a twitter like web page, which should be able to do both the "reading" (get / fetch) and "writing" (post / update) of the JSON file that contains the users' information, such as the contents of tweets, profile image etc.

The problem that I'm not successfully calling the POST when a new message is entered via the text field. It spits a `404 (Not Found)` error. What am I doing wrong?

**[The structure of the working directory]**

```
slutuppgift/
|--                         Static files
|-- index.html              HTML-code 
|-- feed.json               the API JSON-data
|-- src/                
|-- |-- main.js             JavaScript-code to initialize Vue & app.vue
|-- |-- App.vue             Vue-code for the application
|-- |-- components/         Vue-code for components
|-- |-- views/              Vue-code for pages/templates (Vue-router).
|-- |-- router.js           JavaScript-code for Vue-router (URL-structure)
|-- |-- api.js              JavaScript-code for Express.js (the API)
```

**[App.vue file]**

```
<template>
    <form class = "userContainer">
        <div class = "user-avatar"> 
            <img src="avatar/avatar-loggedin.jpg">
        </div>
        <textarea rows = "10" cols = "80" v-model="kweetInput">  </textarea>  
    button class = "kwitterBtn" type = "submit" @click.prevent="newKweet()">Kwitter</button>
    </form>  
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      allJsonData: [],
      pageLoaded: false,
      kweetInput: '',
      userJSON: {
        avatar: 'avatar/avatar-loggedin.jpg',
        username: 'John Doe',
        handle: '@johndoe',
        timestamp: '',
        content: this.kweetInput,
        media: {
          type: '',
          url: ''
        },
        actions: {
          replies: 0,
          rekweets: 0,
          likes: 0
        }
      }
    }  
  },
  methods: {
    newKweet(){
      var self = this;
      alert(self.kweetInput);     

      this.axios.post('/feed.json', {
        userJSON: self.userJSON
      })
      .then(function(response){
        console.log('The output: ');
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log('An error occured...');
        console.log(error);
      });  

      self.kweetInput = '';
      console.log('The end of newKweet() method');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I installed vue-axios and defined it in `main.js`, so it should be ready to be used.

**[main.js file]**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from './router';
import App from './App.vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from '../node_modules/vue-axios';

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router: VueRouter,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**[api.js file]**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const api = express();
const apiUrl = process.env.URL || 'http://localhost';
//const apiPort = parseInt((process.env.PORT || 3001));
const apiPort = 8080;

api.use(express.json());

api.get('/api/feed/get' , (req, res) => {
  //let feedFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../employees.json');  // just an experiment with a simpler file
  let feedFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../feed.json');

  res.type('json');
  res.sendFile(feedFile);
});

api.post('/api/feed/post' , (req, res) => {     //  /api/feed/post      //  ../feed.json
  //let feedFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../employees.json');  // just an experiment with a simpler file
  let feedFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../feed.json');
  let feedContent = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(feedFile));
  let feedPosted = req.body;
  let feedJson = '';

  console.log('/api/feed/post:', feedPosted);

  feedContent.push(feedPosted);

  feedJson = JSON.stringify(feedContent);

  fs.writeFileSync(feedFile, feedJson);

  res.type('json');
  res.sendFile(feedFile);
});

api.listen(apiPort, () => {
  console.log(`API server running at ${apiUrl}:${apiPort}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from defining route wrongly by typo from the developer side, one gets `404` if one types the address wrongly.

Trying to access a dynamically generated address that might probably be deleted could result to `404`

Comment: So either way it's most likely because of a wrongly defined destination? What's the major difference between "route" and "address"? Is ```'/feed.json'``` in my code a route, or address?

Comment: Basically, address is a destination while route is a path you take to your destination. In your own case: `/feed.json` is an address.

Comment: How should the correct address look like if I am to successfully post a "new kweet" to the ```feed.json``` file? I got an error ```POST http://localhost:8080/feed.json 404 (Not Found) ```. Does it look like something is missing?

Comment: You don't need to write the absolute path.

In your `main.js` file, you  need to create a base instance

Comment: `const base = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://example.com'
})

Vue.prototype.$http = base`

Comment: Then in your component, you do `this.$http.get('/feed.json')`

Comment: Actually there was a file named ```api.js```, where path, api, apiUrl, apiPort etc are defined (sorry I forgot to include it in my original post. I updated it a minute ago). Isn't there a way to make the most of the existing ```api.js``` file so I won't have to write the absolute path?